# How to prevent Leafletjs from uninstalling off screen images?

Tags: leaflet

I used the tileLayer method of leafletjs to load my own images, but I found that it will default to uninstalling off screen image resources. I hope that after loading, it will not unload off screen images. Are there any parameters that can be controlled.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#gridlayer-keepbuffer